# How would I properly illustrate the relationship a class has with an enclosing class in UML?

Tags: uml

I have a `Game` class and in that class exists a `KeyInputHandler` class.  I believe this is a "has a" relationship but I am not 100% sure.  If this is indeed a "has a" relationship it would be composition and I know what symbols to use, but if it is something else then I could use some advice.

EDIT:

This is the structure of the two classes I am concerned with.

```
//Import stuff

public class Game extends Canvas { //The Game class

    public Game (){ //Game constructor

    }

    //Other methods and stuff will go here

    private class KeyInputHandler extends KeyAdapter {
        //This is the only other class in my Game, and
        //you can see it is enclosed in the Game class
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game(); // Creates a new game
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for the question - I do think that you are bang on with it being composition. I think the fact that the class itself is inside the parent is more to do with implementation. But the relationship is pretty much Composition, IMO.

Comment: I'll just go with it then... Thanks.

Comment: I'd also say that KeyInputHandler being inside Game is incidental, and doesn't change much about the "hasA". You didn't mean that Game has a field of type KeyInputHandler, didn't you?

Comment: No, the `KeyInputHandler` class is a private class completely enclosed inside the `Game` class... see edited question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From your description, it looks like a Composition relationship.

- cardinality is 1:1 (degenerate case of 1:many)
- lifecycle of composed class (KeyInputHandler) is controlled by composing class (Game)

Assuming those are correct then Composition is appropriate.

A related question worth asking is how you'd describe the relationship among them.  What role does KeyInputHandler play with respect to Game?  That will help the reader understand the "why" of the relationship, not just the "what".

Comment: I am sorry to tell you this answer is wrong. A containment relationship between two classes involve their instances not the classes themselves.If you use the containment relationship between Game and KeyInputHandler you are just specifying that an instance of the Game class has a property typed as KeyInputHandler (it owns an instance of KeyInputHandler). What modeled in the question is quite different.  It is the whole KeyInputHandler class which is defined inside the Game class. To this end the UML provides a different mechanisms called nestingClassifier. See my answer

Comment: To better understand this, look at http://lowcoupling.com/post/47801917915/understanding-uml-associations

Answer (score 0):

The `Game` class here serves like the top-level container, very much like a package I'd say. I guess `KeyInputHandler` is not a static class, and directly calls "back" into `Game`?

In that case, either you directly have a field of type `KeyInputHandler`, or you pass an instance to an environment like SWT that will call it back.

So an association with containment-type composite as @sfinnie suggest would be appropriate. However, there's another possible view in my opinion: you could also treat it from a component-point of view. In that perspective, your `Game` class becomes a component that requires an environment for input (SWT, keyboard, ...). So in this more structural view, you are combining `Game`, `KeyInputHandler`, and e.g. SWT.

Usually in the components-world of Software Engineering, these are exactly those things that have a stable 1:1 relation (stable in the sense that you will be talking to the same object for your entire lifetime).

Maybe you could elaborate how tightly `KeyInputHandler` and `Game` are coupled, i.e. how difficult it would be to put into a separate class, outside of `Game`. That way, you can also gain inside of how they are related (but always remember: "You ain't gonna need it", so if your design works fine, keep it ---we're only talking about the conceptual level here).

Answer (score 0):

I have reversed your java code in my UML tool and got the following result.
Hope this help !!

[alt text http://www.forum-omondo.com/inner_class_description.png](http://www.forum-omondo.com/inner_class_description.png)

Comment: Hummm, that is different.  I have never seen a class actually drawn inside another class in UML.

Comment: You can display the class inside or outside the other class but the structural class diagram view should be a class displayed inside another class. This is what I use with Java but could be different with other language

Comment: @typoknig you have never seen it but is the correct notation for the nestedClassifier property of the Class meta-class which is the construct the specification said shall be used to model inner classes. See my answer

Comment: The diagram has been replaced by an ad.

Answer (score 0):

The UML specification 2.5b1 (the latest) you can find at http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/Beta1/
says that:
*A Class acts as the namespace for various kinds of Classifiers defined within its scope, including Classes. Nested Classifiers are members of the namespace of the containing Class. Classifier nesting is used for reasons of information hiding. Nested Classifiers are used like any other Classifier in the containing Class.*
The property of the Class meta-class used to list the class contained inside a class is called nestingClass, as depicted by the meta-model shown in figure 11.15 pag. 202

Please note (very carefully) that a containment association between two class involves their instances NOT the classes.